# How can I remove double quotes from a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, quotes, double-quotes

I have the following problem:

I have a string that contains multiple E-Mail adresses.
These adresses are not static. I pull them from my database.
So for example when the adresses are pulled and I print the string the output is:

`mails = 'email1', 'email2', 'email3'`

Now I want to make a list out of the string.
So my code is:

`list = [mails]`

But when I print the list, I get the following result:

`["'email1', 'email2', 'email3'"]`

How can I remove the double quotes, so that the output looks like this?

`['email1', 'email2', 'email3']`

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: When you print a list object, the list calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) on each inner object. It is repr() that is causing the double quotes. This is only a matter of display and doesn't affect the contents of the original string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear what you mean. Are you saying that you have a variable named `mails`, that gets a value from your program? And when you do `print(mails)`, the result that you see on screen is **exactly** `'email1', 'email2', 'email3'`? I.e. you do **not** see the `mails = ` part when you use `print`?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have, in your code:

```
mails = 'email1', 'email2', 'email3'
```

That is a tuple of strings, i.e.

```
('email1', 'email2', 'email3')
```

You can simply convert that into a list by casting:

```
mails = list(mails)
```

which will produce

```
['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
```

Of course, all depends on your input data. Normally you would retrieve the data from your database and add it instantly to a list or some data structure that supports the intended functionality on that data better than a list.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex and list comprehension:

```py
import re
my_list = [re.sub(r"'([^']+)'", r"\1", x) for x in my_list]
```

Explanation: What is inside single quotes gets added to group which the replacement string `\1` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this:

```
mails = 'email1', 'email2', 'email3'
mails= list(mails)
print(mails)
```

and now the result will be the same as you want:

```
['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
a_list = json.dumps(emails)
```

Is how i would do it If i wanted a string representation like what is described...